# Unix Domain Sockets Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to establish a connection beetwen my client(.java) and my server(.c) but  everytime i try i got this error:

```
Error in initializing local socket: java.io.IOException: Connection refused
```

I know the problem it's my client:

```
private LocalSocket localReceiver;
try {

        localReceiver = new LocalSocket();
        localReceiver.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("serverSocket"));


        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Done: init()");
    }catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error in initializing local socket: " + e);
    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I can't connect to my server. The way that i'm creating and connecting the socket it's the correct one? I know that i have to do some more stuff after the connection, but right now it's pointless if i can't even connect. 
I tested my server with a different client in .c and it worked.